# Duplicate questions, but low view topics. Flag for moderator?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

I answer a lot of questions on a particular topic, but that topic has relatively low views. A question came up today that has an exact duplicate that I have highlighted as such. However, due to the low view count on the topic, it is unlikely to ever get closed.

Should I flag this to moderators to help get it closed, or should I just ignore it and let it live on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should flag it as `Doesn't Belong here` -> `Exact Duplicate of` and paste the URL.

[image]

That'll raise a flag which will be visible to Moderators & 10k+ users who, if they agree, can vote to close it as well.

Answer (score 1):

[You should stop worrying and love dupes.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)  I wouldn't bother unless they are *exact exact* duplicates.  Not "they're kinda the same" or "they appear to be somewhat related" but "this idiot just reposted that question" kind of dupes.

Comment: yep, it is an exact duplicate, so I will do as @sathya says